# emails in drupal 7 using mime mail module

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7, mime-mail

I was trying to send simple emails in Drupal 7 using rules. It was going good.
At one stage I had to send HTML email, so I enabled "Mime Mail" module. When I enable this module, emails are not being sent. Although I am not even sending HTML and I haven't changed rule either.

I have tried using Mail log and devil module. Cant debug the issue properly.

Looking forward for solution.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've selected `MimeMailSystem` as your `Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class` & `Mime Mail module class`.

You can find these settings at `admin/config/system/mailsystem`

Comment: That was some issue with Mail log, which was not maintaining the logs properly. Anyhow, it has been resolved, Thank you for response :)